# TypeError: roli() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message' "

Tags: python, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Здравствуйет! Я хотел вызвать функцию своего телеграмм бота написанного на Telebot, которая должна была выдавать список кнопок после нажатия. Но при нажатии кнопки "Роли" выдает ошибку **TypeError: roli() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'** во время выполнения функции callback_a. Прошу помочь ее убрать, сам пытался стало только хуже

**Функция создающия и вызывающая ту самую кнопку**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):                                                       
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Роли', callback_data="roli"))
    bot.reply_to(message,'Некое сообщение', reply_markup=markup)
```

**Обработчик нажатия**

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_a(callback):
    if callback.data == 'roli':
        roli()
```

**Сама функция 'Roli'**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['roli'])
def roli(message):
    def klass_mafia():
        pass
    def klass_yakudza():
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Вернуться', callback_data='roli'))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Некое сообщение', reply_markup=markup)

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Мирные', callback_data="klass_mafia"))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Якудза', callback_data="klass_yakudza"))

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Некое сообщение', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `roli()` в `def callback_a(callback):` на `roli(callback.message)`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts